# trying to print a line a text file in c

Tags: c, printf, text-files

i am trying to print a line from a text file then go to the next line and print that until there is no more lines left to print. This is what i have so far, but it only works the first time that i run the program.

```
void ReadFile(FILE *a)
{
    char line[23];
    while(fgets(line, 22, a) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", line);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you closing the stream properly? -> fclose( fp );

Comment: R34lthing, yes i am closing the file at the end of the main loop that this function is called in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to reset the *file pointer* back to the start if you want to do this multiple times with the same `FILE` object:

```
void ReadFile(FILE *a)
{
    char line[23];
    rewind(a);
    while(fgets(line, 22, a) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", line);    // Added new line
    }
}
```

[Reference](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind).

Answer (score 1):

You're not `rewind(a)`ing the file and so every iteration of the function begins from where the last `fgets` left it (EOF, in your case).